# php - merge single array values in one array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array that is generated based on data retrieved from database and looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet","Budget"] [1] => ["Phone","VPN"] )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet","Budget", "Cloud"] [1] => ["Phone","VPN"] )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet","Budget"] [1] => ["Phone","VPN", "POP"] )
```

Desired result would be (based on array examples from above):

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet", "Budget","Phone", "VPN"] )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet", "Budget", "Cloud", "Phone", "VPN"] )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] => ["Tablet", "Budget", "Cloud", "Phone", "VPN", "POP"] )
```

I tried with

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $myarray);
```

and

```
$test = array_merge(...$myarray)
```

but i can't make it work, the values are not merged.

How can i do it?

PHP 7.3.1

Thank you

Comment: `$test = [array_merge(...$myarray)];` fiddle: https://3v4l.org/LvDTn

Comment: Thank you, but my array is not like the one you've tested ($myarray = [["Tablet","Budget", "Cloud"],["Phone","VPN"]];) but is Array ( [0] => ["Tablet","Budget", "Cloud"] [1] => ["Phone","VPN"] ); do i have to do something before calling the array_merge in order to get an array like yours?

Comment: tested the code from fiddle and i'm getting the result Array ( [0] => )

Comment: Your array is the same, `print-r` my array - there's no difference.

Comment: ok, but the result with your code is also different from what i've asked, i need a single key array, not a multikey array: Array ( [0] => ["Tablet", "Budget", "Cloud", "Phone", "VPN"] )

Comment: Please, make sure you understand __arrays__. You have multidimensional array here. it has key `0` on level 1 and keys from 0 to 5 on level 2.

Comment: But i asked for a single level array, not a multidimensional array..can you help me, please?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => ["Tablet", "Budget", "Cloud", "Phone", "VPN", "POP"] )` is a __two level__ array. If you need one level - just use your code `$test = array_merge(...$myarray)`.